# Как расширить логический раздел /home на linux ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Перекопал весь интернет и все возможные способы расширения почему-то не работают у меня. Хочу расширить раздел /home. Он был создан отдельно, как логический раздел. Хочу расширить его на 15.99 гб, которые свободны. Почему-то в gparted свободное место отображается, а если попробовать просмотреть через терминал, то нет.
[image: gparted]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учитывая, что между /home и свободным местом торчат ещё целых два раздела — придётся страдать, переставляя их местами

Comment: (ну или просто передвинуть эти два раздела вправо, но это тоже страдать)

Comment: @andeymal А как их передвинуть? И если я отделю от диска с 195гб память, то тогда можно будет без проблем сделать расширение?

Comment: Ну "на живую" я бы не стал это проворачивать. Грузани `gparted live` и развлекайся там. Бэкап важных данных сделать не забудь.